# Segmentation Failure Reverse Array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I just made a program for reversing the array and i was submitting it on an online site it passed most of the test cases but showed a "Segmentation Fault".After reading about it on google i realized it happens commonly in the following cases:-

- Dereferencing NULL
- Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer
- Dereferencing a pointer that has been freed or has gone out of scope
- Writing off the end of an array

so I think i have some fault ending the array

My code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,n,j,temp=0;
    int arr[20];
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      cin>>arr[i];
    }
    j=i-1; 
    i=0;
    while(i<j)
    {
        temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

}
```

Test Case 
Input
100
242 491 9227 3742 2430 6533 1797 717 9052 9638 3360 8260 7478 9775 3062 295 818 8073 1030 1846 9550 3622 3534 8920 3714 6532 5155 848 51 1579 9413 7049 1948 9388 7358 7819 7956 7826 7089 1877 5628 8738 8604 3538 7328 8652 536 4135 1171 8281 9990 8064 389 796 4529 3576 3694 6979 4784 7359 4210 8853 6866 3283 3564 5204 1201 4954 7124 6426 258 1268 9915 8877 4049 8443 6236 1900 9975 3043 5403 3025 9509 1324 5991 6478 3624 7949 7208 7730 2885 4072 899 1107 5355 5547 1139 5907 4134 9642

Expected Output
9642 4134 5907 1139 5547 5355 1107 899 4072 2885 7730 7208 7949 3624 6478 5991 1324 9509 3025 5403 3043 9975 1900 6236 8443 4049 8877 9915 1268 258 6426 7124 4954 1201 5204 3564 3283 6866 8853 4210 7359 4784 6979 3694 3576 4529 796 389 8064 9990 8281 1171 4135 536 8652 7328 3538 8604 8738 5628 1877 7089 7826 7956 7819 7358 9388 1948 7049 9413 1579 51 848 5155 6532 3714 8920 3534 3622 9550 1846 1030 8073 818 295 3062 9775 7478 8260 3360 9638 9052 717 1797 6533 2430 3742 9227 491 242

Comment: Okay i just realized size of array was wrong. but it won't accept arr[] any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know the size beforehand, or an upper bound on the size?

Comment: Take a look at std::reverse http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: Don't include<bits/stdc++.h>, it's a non standard header.

Comment: I don't have the constrait for the array i need to make it dynamic but it wont accept `arr []`

Comment: @manni Included to cut the hassle of adding other libraries, it's frequent in competitive coding.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I would assume `int arr[20];` implies an upper bound of 20.

Comment: @IlBeldus trying to do it without using `<algorithm>`

Comment: @SaubhagyaSrivastava https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: @SaubhagyaSrivastava nevertheless that page shows the most efficient algorithm

Comment: @IlBeldus Can you please tell me how can i use that algo in this program?

Comment: use std::vector. It is designed for exactly this case

Comment: @pm100 actually i am not using STL in my code about plus i am using `using namespace std;` so i don't understand how can i use the suggested algorithm in the code (without the STL)

Comment: I know you are not using STL. I am recommending that you do. std::vector is a dynamically sized array, exactly what you need

Comment: @SaubhagyaSrivastava in the code under "possible implementation", `first` for you is `arr` and `last` is `arr+n`.
 `std::iter_swap` is trivial to reimplement

Comment: @IlBeldus sorry I'm not able to understand what you are trying to say ?

Comment: @SaubhagyaSrivastava in the page I linked: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse there is a section called "Possible implementation" there there is a template function that is probably the most efficient algorithm. You just have to remove the template and replace `first` with `arr` and `last` with `arr+n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array that holds the values isn't big enough.  As a result, you end up writing past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined beahvior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a crash.

You need to allocate space big enough for the number of values:

```
cin>>n;
int *arr = new int[n];
```

Don't forget to `delete[] arr;` at the end of your program.

EDIT:

If you want to do it the "proper" C++ way, you can instead use a `std::vector`:

```
cin>>n;
std::vector<int> arr(n);
```

This way you don't need to worry about freeing the memory later.  It will happen automatically when `arr` goes out of scope.

Comment: @SaubhagyaSrivastava The most commonly used standard smart pointers are [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Along with `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`, you should very rarely need to use `new` and never have to remember to use `delete`.